# Exporting Excel to data grid view

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datagridview, oledb

I have an Excel file and want to display excel file in a data grid view if user click a button. Columns are

```
Date, Day, Start time, End time, Totaltime, Difftime and Work done.
```

And my sample row data is as follows for A10 row and A11 rows.

A10  01-03-2014         Saturda     8:20        22:30        13:40    4:40      Design

A11  02-03-2014     Sunday        9:00      21:00        11:30      2:30         Coding

My rows lies in the range from 10 to 40 and columns are from A-G

If I import it to data grid view dates and times are not displaying properly. 01/03/2014 appears as 404977. I want code to export the Excel file to datagridview and also datagridview should display the same as Excel. Can anyone explain how to do it in C# with date day, start, end, total, diff, work done as datagridview columns?

[image]

Comment: Export or import? windows form?

Comment: You could use something like Openxml to read the data from excel file, store the data in some POCO objects, and then write it to data grid.  Have you checked the data type for that excel column ? How are you reading the data anyway ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan iwant to display excel in data grid view...

Comment: @Jundev DATA FORMAT FOR THE TIME COLUMS IS H:[MM] AND EXCEL SIS STORING DATES IN DOUBLE FORMAT....

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to import to a window forms datagridview,

Excel 2003,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = "Yoursheetname";
        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                        "C:\\Sample.xls" + 
                        ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        grid_items.DataSource = data;
    }
```

for Excel 2007,

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = "Yoursheetname";
        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                        "C:\\Sample.xlsx" + 
                        ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        grid_items.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Comment: how to display the coloms date ,day ,start... what will be the query for them.... also my row range is 10-40 how to select only rows 10-40 and coloms a-g using the query

Comment: It will automatically get binded, if you want to have a custom columns read on having custom columns for datagridview.

Comment: i want oly rows from 10 to 40 and coloums from a to g to appear in my grid view..how to do it.